# SaveChanges() completes execution method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public ActionResult FunOne(FormCollection values)
{
    var hmm= new Order();
    TryUpdateModel(hmm);

    DB.Tab1.Add(hmm);
    string aaa = "aaa";       //BP1
    DB.SaveChanges();         //BP2
    string bbb = "bbb";       //BP3

    return RedirectToAction("Finish");
    }
}
```

Didn't perform the `return RedirectToAction("Finish");` so I added BP (Breakpoint).
I noticed that BP3 is not performed. I didn't get any error from compiler.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is there any exception thrown? Have you looked at Results Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you stepped through this line by line in the debugger to check?

Comment: @Oscar, You're right, I looked only at **Error List** Meanwhile **Output** gives: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Data you are trying to save have some error and the `DB.SaveChanges();` has not been executed and the Action throws an Exception.

Comment: I checked the database, the PK exist, autoindexable exist... I added `[Key]` in the hmm model and still does not work.

Comment: How? the standard method for MVC. Well matched to the transmitted data model hmm.

Comment: I deleted a table in the database. I created the same way again and it works. The malice of inanimate...